# How to stop Static IP is being overwritten with dynamic IP?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ip, static-ip

I have create a connection from network manager GUI with wired connection and in IPv4 setting tab, with all details like IP address,netmask,gateway and DNS server.

Also change the /etc/network/interface file with below details:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.xx.xxx.xxx
netmask 255.255.xxx.x
gateway 172.xx.xxx.x
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 172.xx.x.x
```

After restarting the machine I got the network connected and from ifconfig output got the IP address as I provided in network manager GUI or in interfaces file.

But the main issue is,this internet connection got disconnected after 10/15 mins.
And this time ip address got change to dynamic ip like 169.XXX.XXX.XXX.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

[Nuke `/var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1391829&page=2).

If that doesn't work, make sure you're not running Network Manager (I'm assuming this is a headless server so I don't expect it to be), WICD or any other network-managing interferer.

If you have NM (et al) and need it, just teach it the same settings as your main `/etc/network/interfaces` config. Bit hacky but it should do the trick.

Comment: Err... how do I undo the nuking? Is there a copy of that file anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that NetworkManager will over ride your settings in /etc/network/interface

Easiest method of configuring your ip address DNS servers is to use NetworkManager

Use "manual method".

Under IPv4, fill in your ip address, netmask, dns server(s), etc

[image]

Your other option, if you want to use /etc/network/interface, would be to disable network manager.

If you are still having a problem, check the logs to see if there is a clue as to why your network connection is being dropped and/or post more information on your hardware.